# How to manage serializataion of Entities that have links to each other?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, serialization

I have a **Vote** and a **Restaurant** entities, when I manage their relations with
`@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` I have a problem.

If I serialize **Restaurant** - everything seems to be fine.

If I serialize **Vote** - fields with `@JsonManagedReference` are omitted. And I have this JSON:

```json
{
    "id": 50,
    "voteDate": "2021-08-04"
}
```

I would appreciate if you could tell me, how I can serialize both objects without omitting fields and getting `StackOverflow` error.

Some entity's code are omitted for brevity:

```java
@Entity
public class Vote extends AbstractBaseEntity {
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private Restaurant restaurant;
    
    private LocalDate voteDate;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = {"votes", "dishes"})
public class Restaurant extends AbstractNamedEntity {

    String address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Dish> dishes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Vote> votes;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert entities to DTO objects. Add postfix `Entity` to the entities. And use names without postfix for DTO.

```java
@Entity
class VoteEntity {


}

class Vote {

  private String voteDate;
  
  private String restaurantName;

}
```

Convert entities to DTO on the service level and do the serialization after that.

Comment: Thank you, I would also appreciate if you could tell me, if decide to still have an object of Restaurant in my Vote. 
Would it be a bad practice to create a static class VoteStaticRestaurant with multiple additional fields ( but no link to VoteDto ) in my VoteDto class.

And to do the same for RestaurantDto ( create a static RestaurantStaticVote class with no link to RestaurantDto ).
That fixes my problem but will people laugh at it when they see?)

Comment: @KlausKöhler Please don't use `Dto` postfix and `Static` part of the class name. You can use any DTO classes that are convent to you. You can create a pull request with all the classes on github and add me to reviewers.